# Get parent of symbolic link instead of original folder

Tags: finder, bash

I have a project with node_modules folder that contains a symbolic link to another project. The problem that inner project takes configs from parent project (etc ../../../config) and thus cannot find it because of the relative path starting from the original folder instead of a symbolic link.

Example:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir -p a/b/c
$ ln -s a/b/c d
$ cd d
$ ls ../
```

Will display content of b folder. But I need to display listing of ~ directory. How to do it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your question but assuming your shell is `bash` or `ksh` would `ls "$OLDPWD"` or `ls ~-` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not how symbolic links work.

From the man page (`man ln`)

> The ln utility creates a new directory entry (linked file) for the
>   file name specified by target_file.  The target_file will be created
>   with the same file modes as the source_file.  It is useful for
>   maintaining multiple copies of a file in many places at once without
>   using up storage for the “copies”; instead, **a link “points” to the
>   original copy.**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So, how do you get around this?  Use an *environment variable.*  For example:

```
$ mkdir -p /a/b/c
$ FOO='/a/b/c'
$ cd ~
$ cd $FOO
$ pwd
/a/b/c
```

Note, you should use *absolute paths* when doing this; using relative paths can and will have unintended consequences.

Comment: Which `ln` man page are you quoting from. Is that an exact quote or a paraphrased quote? I'm asking because what's quoted is not what I'm finding in the man page in macOS.

Comment: macOS.  It's right under the `DESCRIPTION` headding.

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: Checked on High Sierra and El Capitan.

Comment: Okay, I've looked at the `ln` man page in OS X El Capitan, macOS High Sierra and macOS Mojave. The paragraph you've quoted doesn't exist as quoted in all three. So is what you quoted an exact quote or a paraphrased quote?

Comment: but it doesn't solve my problem, the example was just example to explain the problem with symbolic links